# Swift Change View Position after rotate

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app that allow user to use in both potrait and landscape orientation. My goal is to have a view like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tsKv.jpg) (landscape on the left and potrait on the right. I managed to reposition the view using the following code

```
func changeViewAfterRotate(orientation : UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    if (orientation == .LandscapeLeft ||
        orientation == .LandscapeRight)
    {
        headlineImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width/2 , self.view.frame.size.height)

        let statusbarHeight = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height
        let navBarHeight = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height
        let viewHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - statusbarHeight - navBarHeight!
        let titleHeight = self.headlineTitleView.frame.size.height + statusbarHeight + navBarHeight!


        let yPos = statusbarHeight + navBarHeight!

        headlineTitleView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, yPos, self.view.frame.size.width/2 , self.headlineTitleView.frame.size.height)
        headlineScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, titleHeight, self.view.frame.size.width/2 , viewHeight - titleHeight)

        let fixedHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: headlineTitleView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 134)
                    view.addConstraint(fixedHeight)
    }
    else
    {
        headlineImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/3)

        print("headlineImage.frame.size.width \(headlineImage.frame.size.width)")

        let titleHeight =  self.headlineImage.frame.size.height

        headlineTitleView.frame = CGRectMake(0, titleHeight , self.view.frame.size.width , self.headlineTitleView.frame.size.height)
        headlineScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, titleHeight + self.headlineTitleView.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width , self.view.frame.size.height - titleHeight - self.headlineTitleView.frame.size.height)

        let equalWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: headlineScrollView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraint(equalWidth)
    }
```

My problem is is I rotate the IPad for the first time for each view, it will goes like this : [landscape on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzrPL.jpg) . It went back to normal after I rotate the IPad a few times. Can anyone help me to solve this issues?

Comment: Did you use auto layout in your interface builder?

Comment: Not sure why you're doing this in code. This can be done in interface builder with much less typing. I would watch this video from ~30 minute mark discussing size classes and orientations. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-411/

Comment: @Lumialxk yes I did.

Comment: @SyafiqMastor If your constraints conflicted,you should change your constraints rather add new ones.

Comment: @AdrianB I am new with this. Thanks for the link. I will watch it.

Comment: @Lumialxk I see. I will try. Thanks very much